# Helmholtz decomposition of a vector field in Fourier space with Python

Tags: numpy, fourier-transform, vector

I have a 3D vector field and I want to extract its divergence-free part (also called transverse component), using the *Helmholtz decomposition*.
In principle, this can be done in the Fourier space, as illustrated [here](https://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition.html) in the proof (and also reported [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/quick-and-simple-discrete-2d-helmholtz-hodge-decomposition-using-ffts)).

I wrote this Python function, implementing this straightforward calculation, where the input is a vector field of shape (3,N,N,N), since it has 3 components and is defined in a 3D square grid with NxNxN nodes and size equal to `boxsize`:

```
def helmholtz_decomposition(vector_field, boxsize):
    kx, ky, kz = np.meshgrid(2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[1], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[1])),
                             2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[2], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[2])),
                             2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(vector_field.shape[3], boxsize / (vector_field.shape[3])),
                             indexing='ij')

    k_vector = np.array([kx, ky, kz])
    k_squared = kx ** 2 + ky ** 2 + kz ** 2
    k_squared[k_squared == 0] = 1e-12  # Avoid division by zero

    vector_field_fourier = np.fft.fftn(vector_field)

    dot_product = kx * vector_field_fourier[0] + \
                  ky * vector_field_fourier[1] + \
                  kz * vector_field_fourier[2]

    potential_part_fourier = (dot_product / k_squared) * k_vector
    solenoidal_part_fourier = vector_field_fourier - potential_part_fourier

    potential_part = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(potential_part_fourier))
    solenoidal_part = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(solenoidal_part_fourier))

    return potential_part, solenoidal_part
```

Here, the potential and solenoidal parts should be curl-free and divergence-free respectively.

The problem is that the divergence of the solenoidal part is not zero.
I have already checked that the solenoidal part in the Fourier space is perpendicular to the wave vector `k_vector`, as it should be.

**For example**: the divergence of the original total vector field is `0.0111`, while the divergences of its solenoidal and potential parts are `0.00584` and `0.00555` respectively.

Does anyone know where the mistake is?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to scicomp! Is the number of real space mesh points equal to the number of cells? Or do you have n+1 DOF for your n cells?

Comment: Thank you @MPIchael . The number of grid points is equal to the length of the array, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details in python/numpy, but many errors in fourier algorithms stem from missing or doubled normalization. In your example you scale by 2*pi? See for example: 
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66058/am-i-supposed-to-normalize-fft-in-python

Comment: Unfortunately, the 2*pi factor doesn't change the result. But I will think about it again. Thanks a lot @MPIchael.